# PHP getting values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

In php how would I get the value 'error' in this array below? I did a `var_dump($myArray);`

I tried echo `$myArray[0][0];` and `$myArray[0];` but neither of these worked.

```
array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["error"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["message"]=>
          string(27) "Invalid OAuth access token."
          ["type"]=>
          string(14) "OAuthException"
          ["code"]=>
          int(190)
          ["fbtrace_id"]=>
          string(11) "GJb4ZZLyAll"
        }
      }
    }
```

**What I am actually looking for is to check the value of $myArray[0][0]; If my code works that value will be "id". If it didn't work it will be "error". So I need to see if it says "id" or "error".**

Comment: echo `$myArray[0]['error']['message']`;

Comment: Try `var_dump( array_column($myArray, ''error" ));` and `var_dump( array_column($myArray[0], ''error" ));`

Comment: What I am actually looking for is to check the value of $myArray[0][0]; If my code works that value will be "id". If it didn't work it will be "error". So I need to see if it says "id" or "error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from my understanding you want to check the value of the key. So we get the keys as an array with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), with this you then can access the first key and check if it is `id` or `error`, e.g.

```
$keys = array_keys($myArray[0]);

if($keys[0] == "id") {
    //good
} elseif($keys[0] == "error") {
    //bad
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Rizier123. Now I know why you have 43k points. :)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can access array elements by name. So to get the value of "error" type:

```
$value = $myArray[0]["error"];
```